# jQuery DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved not working on each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have form, which has duplicated section. Users can add the same section as many time they want.

**This is my code**

```
jQuery(function ($){
  $('html').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function () {
    $(".thevoornaam, .date_of_birth, .livingkid, .right, .limitSelected, .pijlers, .total_pijlers").bind("keyup change", function() {
        if ($(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && $('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10  && $(".livingkid").is(':checked') && $(".right").is(':checked') && $(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "1" && $(".pijlers").val() != null && $(".total_pijlers").val() != null)   {
            $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
        } 
        else if ($(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && $('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10  && $(".livingkid").is(':checked') && $(".right").is(':checked') && $(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "0")   {
          $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#stepbirth").addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

When there this section only 1 time in the DOM this function works fine. But there are more it stops validate.

How can i this code to be work on each element?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Show us the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it fails when you have it repeated is that `$(".thevoornaam").val()` and such will return the value of the **first** element with that class, not the element related to the structure where the event occurred.

To work within the structure, use the event object that your function receives, but finding the outermost element of the structure and using `find` on it instead of global `$()` calls. For instance, if the structure's overall parent has the class `example`, you'd do:

```
$('html').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function (event) {
// --------------------------------------------------------^
    var structure = $(event.target).closest(".example");
    structure.find(".thevoornaam, .date_of_birth, .livingkid, .right, .limitSelected, .pijlers, .total_pijlers").bind("keyup change", function() {
// -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (structure.find(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1
// ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
});
```

Also note that you have at least one element identified by ID, `#stepbirth`. If that element is repeated, you'll need to identify it with a class, not an ID.

**But**, several things could be improved in this code:

1. DOM mutation events were superceded by [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) **years** ago.
2. `bind` was superceded by [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) years ago.
3. Since jQuery makes `change` bubble, there's no need for using mutation observers at all, just watch for `change` on the container where these things happen and use the same `closest`/`find` trick as the one used above, but within the `change` handler.
4. The only reason that `$('.total_pijlers').val() != null` would ever be false would be if there were no `.total_pijlers` element at all, or the element that matched didn't have a `value` property (e.g., isn't an `input` element). Otherwise, it always returns a string, and **all** strings are `!= null`. The only values that `!= null` is `false` for are `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will bind all found elements repeatedly. try to use this instead.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on("keyup change", ".thevoornaam, .date_of_birth, .livingkid, .right, .limitSelected, .pijlers, .total_pijlers",
        function () {
            if ($(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && $('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10 && $(".livingkid").is(':checked') && $(".right").is(':checked') && $(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "1" && $(".pijlers").val() != null && $(".total_pijlers").val() != null) {
                $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
            } else if ($(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && $('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10 && $(".livingkid").is(':checked') && $(".right").is(':checked') && $(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "0") {
                $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
            } else {
                $("#stepbirth").addClass("disabled");
            }
        }
    );
});
```

We don't need to bind on node change, jquery already do it for you if you use this code.

Comment: I have already try this without DOMNode function. Did not work :(

Comment: Which point didn't work? when you append new element and keyup change event doesn't work for new element?